# Secure enterprise wiki technology?

Tags: tools, recommendations, wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a secure wiki technology that will allow shared note taking and documentation. Security, organization, and revision control are critical. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Is running it over an SSL connection with an encrypted database secure enough for you?

Comment: And logins of course too.

Comment: I am not sure. Of course the more security the better. (e.g. would Amazon/facebook/groupon development team use such a method of security?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any wiki that has logins, a database that can be encrypted, and runs on SSL should provide enough security for you. You will also need to take security measures as you would with any system - physical access to PCs and the server, making sure that you can trust your users etc. You can ask specific questions on http://security.stackexchange.com.

Every wiki I've seen has revision control.

As for organisation, you probably need to be more specific.

Comment: Can you give some examples of reputable/popular ones?

Comment: Mediawiki, which is what wikipedia is built on, is familiar to people. Dokuwiki is specifically designed for documentation. Confluence isn't free unlike the other two, but has support for multiple wikis.